# how to get confirmations about many transaction at once using bitcore node or bitcoind rpc?

Tags: bitcoind, bitcore

how to get the confirmations of many transaction at once using bitcore node or bitcoind rpc?

I think it's possible to get the confirmation of a single transaction using getrawtransaction of bitcoind rpc, but i want to check the confirmations of multiple transaction by one call. Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solutions (depending on your use case)

1. Use JSON 2.0 batch requests (supported in Core)
2. Use REST with binary export https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/REST-interface.md
3. Use the wallet if your set of scripts you want to watch is known. Use `list transactions` to get all relevant transactions of a set of keys/scripts

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in `bitcoind` RPC without modifying the RPC's code

As to `Bitcore`, I'm not aware of its RPC usage and features

Answer (score 0):

Based on the developer reference guide https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference There doesn't seem to be a direct approach.

However, if you only care about transaction that are below certain number of confirmations, say 6, and deem anything greater than that as `confirmed`, then I'd simply use `listsinceblock` with a block header hash that's 6 below the head tip. In this case, you'll either find your transaction in this list with the `confirmations` field you need, or your transaction has more than 6 `confirmations`.

Not exactly what you look for, but could work depending on what you really care.